# SVG out of viewBox should be zoomable

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Hi I am trying really hard to solve this problem. Initially I have an `svg`-element and inside of it a `g`-element to make zooming in `D3` also possible in Safari. I append a `D3 Force-Directed Graph` to that `g`-element after generating it. Zooming works perfectly fine so far.

The `Force-Directed Graph`is generated as preserved here: https://observablehq.com/@d3/disjoint-force-directed-graph

Initial `svg`-element created:

```
svg.value = d3
    .select("#network")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .append("g");
```

Adding the chart:

```
d3.select("#network").selectAll("svg g > *").remove();
d3.select("#network").select("svg g").node().append(chart);
```

And the zoom-function afterwards:

```
const svgZoom = d3.select("#network svg");

const g = d3.select("#network svg g");

svgZoom.call(
    d3
      .zoom()
      .on("zoom", function () {
         g.attr("transform", d3.zoomTransform(this));
        })
);
```

Now the issue is that the graph always gets cut. I already tried `visibility:visible` on each of those elements, still not working. Even if I set a `viewBox` much bigger than the actual content, or if I set the size of the graph to a minimum, the graph will always get cut to a rectangle.

What I want to accomplish is add the graph full-size and by zooming out the overflowing elements get visible. I do not want to get the height and width of the container and minimize the size of each graph drawn, because some graphs are much bigger than the other ones and I want to keep the initial size of the nodes.

**How it currenty looks**

[Without Zooming Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZrrR.png)

[Zooming Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Leg.png)

Comment: Can you turn that into a runnable snippet so we can see what you're seeing? (in [mcve] form of course: don't include all your data, just include the bare minimum to show off the problem)

Comment: I added two images of how it currently looks I hope this helps :)

Comment: Nevermind, somehow (don't ask me why) the graph itself cuts the boundaries, adding `overflow:visible` to the Force-Directed Graph solved the problem:

Comment: it solved the symptom, not the problem: your viewBox attribute indicates the clipping rectangle for data inside your SVG file.

Comment: I tried to adjust the viewBox but it only shrunk the graph initially rather than just allowing it to overflow and be zoomable.. how could I also solve the problem, additionally to the symptom?

Comment: Right, because SVG has _two_ size indicators, not one: it has its own `viewBox` attribute, which determines at what min/max values content gets clipped, and then it has the `width` and `height` attributes, which tell the page how much space this image will take up (just like on `<img>`). And note that those are _completely independently_ of the SVG content. If you want to "see more", you need to increase your viewBox, and _independently_ of that change you need to make sure to either set the `width` and `height` values so that the SVG has the right size on your page, or do that through CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph itself cuts the boundaries, adding `overflow:visible` to the Force-Directed Graph solved the problem.